# Node.js require webpacked modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack, node-modules

I'm trying to get rid of the thousand files you get once you `npm install` various modules having their own dependencies.

Thus I was thinking of *compiling* only the libraries using **webpack** into one javascript file (and other required resources), then loading it to the Node.js project this way :

- Entry point, that will be compiled to bundle by webpack.

  ```
  module.exports = {
      lodash : require('lodash'),
      colors : require('colors'),
      test : require('test'),
      abc : require('abc')
  } ;
  ```
- Main

  ```
  var { lodash, colors, test, abc } = require('./lib/bundle') ;
  ```

The problem I got is that some modules require system (or uncompilable) modules, such as `fs`, and webpack tries to bundle them to.
You just have to specify in the `webpack.config.js` file :

```
node: {
    fs : "empty",
    electron : "empty"
}
```

However, once packed into bundle, it seems that every `require('fs')` is replaced by `Object.freeze({})` because of this setting, and then the modules fail using `fs`.

---

Would anyone have a solution for using packed modules in a Node.js project ?

*P.S.: I tried using **yarn** with `yarn autoclean --force` to remove all unnecessary files, but it only removed 5% to 10% of the total.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem using the current `node` config object and set `fs: 'empty'` is that it will provide an empty object for those modules. More info about Webpack Node [here](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/node/#node).

You can set the Webpack `target` property to [`'node'`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/target/#string)

> Compile for usage in a Node.js-like environment (uses Node.js `require` to load chunks and not touch any built in modules like `fs` or `path`)

```
module.exports = {
  target: 'node'
};
```

Read more about Webpack [Targets](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/targets/)

Also, to import a built-in module,  use [`__non_webpack_require__`](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-variables/#__non_webpack_require__-webpack-specific-)

> Generates a `require` function that is not parsed by webpack